# Getting line after text between 'a' tag using beautifulsoup and Python

Tags: python, html, url, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the following text:

`Venom Twin Docking Station for Xbox One - White`

The text comes from the following HTML code:

```
<a href="/product/6045870?clickPR=clearance:1:339" data-test="component-product-card-title" target="_self" itemprop="name" class="ProductCardstyles__Title-h52kot-12 PQnCV">
               <meta itemprop="url" content="/product/6045870?clickPR=clearance:1:339">
               Venom Twin Docking Station for Xbox One - White
            </a>
```

The python code I'm using is:

```
productCardCode = BeautifulSoup(str(div), features="html.parser") #gets the original HTML code 

print(productCardCode.find('a').contents[0]) #trying to find the product name
```

But instead the code that is printed is:

```
<meta itemprop="url" content="/product/6045870?clickPR=clearance:1:339">
```

does anyone know how to use beautifulsoup to get the product name and not the meta tag line?

Cheers!

Comment: how about `.contents[2].strip()`?

Comment: Tried that, gave me a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_text()` method:

```
print(productCardCode.find('a').get_text(strip=True))
```

Comment: @James The page is probably loaded dynamically. Using the HTML snippet you provided, it does work

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: Link is https://www.argos.co.uk/clearance/technology/c:29949/clearance:true/opt/page:1/

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.

Instead of using the `.contents`, use `.text` and get the title.

> `print(productCardCode.find('a').text.strip()`

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"}
url = 'https://www.argos.co.uk/clearance/technology/c:29949/clearance:true/opt/page:1/'
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

a = soup.find('a', class_='ProductCardstyles__Title-h52kot-12 PQnCV')
print(a.text.strip())
```

```
Venom Twin Docking Station for Xbox One - White
```